# How to invoke a method on Optional in minimal scenario

Tags: java, java-8, gson, option-type

I have Json which can look like this:

```
{
    "workshop_name" : "ABC"
    "user_name" : "DEF"
}
```

In my app `workshop_name` is not mandatory, so it can came in minimal version:

```
{
    "user_name" : "DEF"
}
```

Now I was thinking about using Java8 Optional to get `workshop_name` from JSON. I was using org.json library and `JSONObject`. I could easily check optional like this:

```
public static EnrichContext createEnricher(JSONObject json) {
    EnrichContext enrichContext = new EnrichContext();
    enrichContext.setWorkshopName(Optional.ofNullable(json.getString("workshop_name")).orElse("DEFAULT"));
    enrichContext.setUserName(json.getString("user_name"));
}
```

I was forced to switch to GSON where it looks a little bit different.

```
json.get("workshop_name").getAsString();
```

This means that I have a new object in the middle after calling `get` on JsonObject (from GSON).

I tried to use nested Optional check, but it looks just too complex.

What I figured out is:

```
enrichContext.setWorkshopName((Optional.ofNullable(json.get("workshop_name")).orElse(new JsonPrimitive("DEFAULT"))).getAsString());
```

I don't like an idea of creating new `JsonPrimitive` on every read. Is there more optimal way for that issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is use a `Optional<String>` instead of a `Optional<JsonPrimitive>`

```
String workshopName = Optional.ofNullable(json.get("workshop_name"))
                              .map(JsonElement::getAsString)
                              .orElse("DEFAULT");
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Like the idea of using Method Reference here as well. Optimal and good looking.